# Minimal number of edges in an directed graph that ensures the existence of a cycle

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I need to find the minimal number of edges in an directed graph with $n$ vertices, that ensures the existence of a cycle in the graph, and proof that for every directed graph with $n$ vertices and that number of edges (or more) there is a cycle.

I tried to find it for small values of $n$ and find a pattern, but even this didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that you can put one edge between every pair of vertices without creating a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The number you are looking for is one more than the maximum number of arcs in an acyclic digraph.

A digraph $D$ is acyclic if and only if there is a total order on the vertices such that arcs go only from vertices earlier in the order to ones later in it. You can imagine putting all the vertices on a line and allowing arcs from left to right. Thus, we can put an arc between any pair of vertices as long as we respect this ordering, implying we can have $\binom{|V(D)|}{2}$ arcs at most in a directed acyclic graph. Hence, the answer to your question is $\binom{|V(D)|}{2}+1$.